# Vue3js: how to loop over array exacly 5 times and conditionaly check elements inside?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, vue.js, vuejs3

please note, that I spend the last 2h searching through SO's similar subjects, to get to a solution, but failed. That's why I ask you now for help.

I am trying to achieve the following:

I have a scoreboard with some results, which should look like this:

- John Doe 100 pts
- John Smith 50 pts
- No Name
- No Name
- No Name

I have an array for this called `scoreBoardArray`.

```
data() {
  return {
     scoreBoardArray: [
        { id: '1', name: 'John Doe', pts: 100 },
        { id: '2', name: 'John Smith', pts: 50 },
     ],
   }
},
```

I can loop through it, but fail to do it exactly 5 times and spit out the "No Name", when no record is found.

My code (and my attempts to solve the problem):

```html
<ul>
   <li v-for="item in scoreBoardArray" :key="item.id">
      <span v-if="item.id">{{ item.name }} {{ item.pts }}</span>
      <span v-if="!item.id">No Name</span
   </li>
</ul>
```

of course, I have tried to solve the problem with the use of a `computed` property and a simple `for(let i=0; i<6; i++) {...}` loop but somehow cannot get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a computed property to [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) the first 5 elements in `scoreBoardArray[]` and to get the number of `"No Name"` dummy items needed (named `topScores` and `dummyLength`, respectively):

```js
export default {
  computed: {
    topScores() {
      return this.scoreBoardArray
        .slice()                      // create a copy
        .sort((a,b) => b.pts - a.pts) // sort by points
        .slice(0, 5)                  // first 5
    },
    dummyLength() {
      return Math.max(0, 5 - this.topScores.length)
    }
  }
}
```

And update the template to render the computed props in a `v-for`, rendering the `topScores` items and then `dummyLength` dummy items:

```html
<ul>
  <li v-for="item in topScores" :key="item.id">
    <span>{{ item.name }} ({{ item.pts }})</span>
  </li>
  <li v-for="n in dummyLength">No Name</li>
</ul>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-show-5-elems?file=src/App.vue)

Comment: If you mean "duplicate keys", it doesn't matter in the second loop. They're all rendered to the same exact element, so they don't really need to be keyed.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, this is something you could achieve with a computed property.

Try just adding some empty objects to the end of your array to pad it out to 5 values.

```js
computed: {
  scoreboard() {
    let append = []
    const appendCount = 5 - this.scoreBoardArray
    for (let i = 0; i < appendCount; i++) {
      append[i] = {}
    }
    return [...this.scoreBoardArray, ...append]
  }
}
```

But since these objects are empty you'll encounter problems with your `v-for` loop keys.
To fix it you could use indices as keys:

```
<li v-for="(item, index) in scoreboard" :key="index">
```